# Can a user create forms in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm officially stuck. I'm am building a django application for work purposes. Staff users should be able to create forms using the django admin. The forms should the be able to display on the website with variable labels. Check link for html [setup](https://ibb.co/dbiZP7). The labels above the inputs should be editable from the django admin for each specific form.

I would also like for users to be able to create as many fields as they like. So for example in the image in the link, there are 8 input fields. Is there any way to do this with a django form/model? I looked at the django forms-builder extension. Basically I want the functionality of being able to press "add another field", but with everything else that comes with the forms-builder package.

The form should be stored in the database attached to the corresponding label of that field.

I've created my own abstract user, and one user should only be able to fill out a particular form once. But should be able to fill out different forms though.

One form should be able to be filled out by many users.

Every idea is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[django-forms-builder](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder) might actually be a good fit for your case. This module provides an ability to modify forms and add fields from the admin interface.

Regarding your constraint with allowing a particular user to submit form only once, there are at least two ways to do it:

First and obvious one would be simply to check that condition in a view, before showing the actual form to a user. You can use request.user instance to check if his username is already in a list of respondents to this form.

Another possible solution would be to use Signals that are provided with django-forms-builder module. They allow you to catch form submission moment either when the form data is valid or not. You can add your custom logic there, e.g. raise alert if a user has already submitted this form before.

Comment: Thanks for your take on this. I guess you are right about the module. How would you go about editing the fields in order to make them fit the application? As mentioned, I really only need a small amount of the functionality it comes with.

Comment: According to django-forms-builder docs, each form added from the admin gets its own url. However, if you don't need that, you can simply do not include django-forms-builder in your project's urls, but create a custom views with your own logic instead. And you can use `{% render_built_form form_instance %}` template tag in order to render particular form in your template.